# Upload file asynchronously using generic handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ashx, generic-handler

I've used the code bellow to upload a file to server asynchronously:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="file_upload" action="UploadFile.ashx" target="upload-target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="javascript:return uploadClicked();">
    <input type="file" id="newFile" name="newFile" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <iframe id="upload-target" name="upload-target"></iframe>
</form>
```

After the submit button clicked, the function **uploadClicked()** will be fired:

```
function uploadClicked() {
    if (condition == true)
        return true; // the form will submit
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now the generic handler **UploadFile.ashx** will save the file and return the result:

```
if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    context.Request.Files["newFile"].SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Images/myFile.png"));
    response.Write("DONE");
}
else
{
    response.Write("FAILED");
}
```

This works well and the result will be showing in the iframe tag.

Is there anyway to get the result ("DONE" or "FAILED") in client-side like this ?

```
function uploadFinished()
{
     if ( response == "DONE" )
     {
          // show the result
     }
     else
     {
          // show error
     }
}
```

Please help me doing this **without using JQuery.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`XHR2 FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object to upload the file to the server asynchronously and retrieve the response from the server handler:

```
function uploadClicked() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById('newFile');
    fd.append(file.name, file.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = document.getElementById('file_upload');
    xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // xhr.responseText will contain the response from the server
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);

    // We are submitting the form asynchronously
    return false;
}
```